# QGLWidget::setFormat replacement in Qt 5.2

Tags: qt

I am trying to set the format of my custom `QGLWidget`:

```
ViewportWidget::ViewportWidget(QWidget *parent)
  : QGLWidget(parent), m_glrenderer()
{
  // Change GLFormat here instead of passing it to ctor
  //   ==>> Ctor API remains unchanged so it can be called by Qt Designer generated classes
  QGLFormat glFormat;
  glFormat.setVersion(3, 2);
  glFormat.setProfile(QGLFormat::CoreProfile);
  glFormat.setSampleBuffers(true);
  glFormat.setDoubleBuffer(true);

  setFormat(glFormat); // Works but obsolete
  //this->context()->setFormat(glFormat); // Does NOT work
}
```

However, **[`QGLWidget::setFormat`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qglwidget-obsolete.html#setFormat)** is obsolete. What is the right way to replace it with `Qt 5.2`?

**NOTES:**

Something like the following works fine too:

```
ViewportWidget::ViewportWidget(const QGLFormat &glformat,
                               QWidget *parent)
  : QGLWidget(glformat, parent), m_glrenderer()
{
}
```

The problem is that it is not an ideal solution for me because as far as I know, if I want to integrate my custom `QGLWidget` with Qt Designer, then constructor must be like:

```
ViewportWidget::ViewportWidget(QWidget *parent)
  : QGLWidget(parent), m_glrenderer()
{...}
```

**ALREADY TRIED**

```
this->context()->setFormat(glformat);
```

=> Empty/blank GLwidget

```
  QGLContext *ctx = this->context();
  ctx->setFormat(glformat);
  this->setContext(ctx);
```

=> Crashes the application

Comment: Try setting the format through `QGlContext::setFormat()` and then `QGLWidget::setContext()`

Comment: I did:   QGLContext *ctx = this->context();
  ctx->setFormat(glformat);
  this->setContext(ctx); but it now crashes the application.

Comment: I just noticed that QGLwidget::setContext is obsolete too.